# Unexpected animation when trying to copy navbar from LESS to basic CSS

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am trying to copy a navbar that is written in LESS to basic CSS as I am just learning it.

```
[https://codepen.io/mrmlnc/pen/gpKbXM][1]
```

I want the border-bottom be behave the same as in LESS but I get a jitter/animation when I try to copy it as seen on .brand and when I don't use the line-height property I don't get the border to be on the bottom of the navbar. 
Also when you look at the navbar-right class I don't get the border-bottom to reach to the next element. The Above border will only underline the above class and not connect to the next element as in the example. My Attempt:

https://codepen.io/atocx/pen/JyvaqY

Comment: Have you tried using [less2css](http://less2css.org/)? It will be very helpful here.

Comment: Have you tried reducing the amount of code to be as small as possible while still reproducing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing jittery animation on your `.brand` element (which has your name as the text) is because line-height does not support subpixel values (i.e. when tweening, the browser jumps from one integer to another).

What you can do is actually to create a pseudo-element that is positioned absolutely within the parent. It is set close to the text with a positive `bottom` value, and upon hover, the `bottom` value is set to 0 so that it sticks to the bottom of the element.

```
.brand {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 64px;
}
.brand::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 20px;  /* This is an arbitrarily decided value */
  opacity: 0;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #673ab7;
  border-bottom-width: 4px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
}
.brand:hover::before {
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

For a proof-of-concept example, see the snippet below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 20px;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #333;
}

.menu-container {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 64px;
  border: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* Shadow needs position "relative" */
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  position: relative;
}

.navbar {
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-right {
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.brand {
  color: #555;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  line-height: 64px;
  position: relative;
}
.brand::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #673ab7;
  border-bottom-width: 4px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
}

.brand:hover {
  color: #333;
}
.brand:hover::before {
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.about {
  color: #555;
  border: transparent;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-width: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
}

.about:hover {
  color: #333;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #673ab7;
  border-bottom-width: 4px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.projects {
  color: #555;
  border: transparent;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-width: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
}

.projects:hover {
  color: #333;
}

.contact {
  color: #555;
  border: transparent;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-width: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
}

.contact:hover {
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="menu-container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="#" class="brand">Florian Dietrich</a>
      <div class="navbar-right">
        <a href="#" class="about">About</a>
        <a href="#" class="projects">Projects</a>
        <a href="#" class="contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the css properties that you don't want to animate on the normal state, instead of hover. 
Check this code pen, I have set the line height and the bottom border properties at the normal state.

```
    https://codepen.io/bmax/pen/JyBWGa?editors=0100
```

the code goes like this:

```
.brand {
  color: #555;
  border: transparent;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  line-height: 64px;
}
.brand:hover {
   color: #333;
   border-bottom-style: solid;
   border-bottom-color: #673ab7;
 }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! 
Do you know how I can make it for "navbar-right" as in my example? I mean that the bottom-border touches with each link? 
So far it is too small and only applies to the link itself.